# Adding SocialCommentControl to a page

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-2013

I have created a page layout for my publishing site. On this page layout i want to add a commenting and rating option.

The rating options shows up just fine on the page but the commentcontrol doesn't seem to be there...

After some research i put the commentcontrol in a webpartzone but this didn't affect the outcome.

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

This is my code for adding the commenting part:

```
<div data-name="WebPartZone">
            <!--CS: Start Web Part Zone Snippet-->
            <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
                <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="x0e5f5212505f48a9aac43df13eeae4f9" AllowCustomization="True" AllowPersonalization="False" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" LockLayout="True" Orientation="Vertical">-->
                    <!--MS:<ZoneTemplate>-->
                        <!--SPM:<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePointPortalControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>-->
                        <p>Comment:</p><!--MS:<SharePointPortalControls:SocialCommentControl ID="CommentControl" runat="server"/>-->                        
                    <!--ME:</ZoneTemplate>-->
                <!--ME:</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>-->

            <!--CE: End Web Part Zone Snippet-->
        </div>
```

BTW, i am working in the html file using sharepoint 2013.

thnx

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your user profile service app in Central Admin? I couldn't even get into it via Central Admin; in the logs I was getting "This User Profile Application's connection is currently not available" So I deleted the service app, recreated, iisreset and presto! All my comment controls magically appeared.